# Thread with a repeating timeout(Stop timeout and reset it later after an event)

Tags: java, multithreading

*I need a system to timeout(continue code) if it's not stopped for some time being able to reset later.*

My problem is when I synchronize to a Map it allows me to check if a key exists, but by the time I'm done and clean things up the thread has already checked if it has been cleaned up. Of course if any of that made sense it means the thread thinks I didn't clean it up when I will.

This should allow me to pause the cleanup thread before checking and then have it reset timeout and continue checking once I'm done.

*I'm very new to multi-threading and would like anything to point me in the right direction(Things to read to help with this etc). I don't know where to start or anything that could achieve this.*

Code Example(Hope this makes sense :) )

```
TestLock lock = new TestLock();
//The lock would get stored with other data See Below: Foo data = map.get("foo");
new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Simply holds idle until the lock timesout.
        lock.waitForTimeout(TimeUnit.MILISECONDS, 500); //Timeout is half a second
        //Code can continue here if the lock hasn't got reset by the time it times out.
        //Timeout will not countdown while it's stopped. See Below: code.getTimeoutLock().stop();
        //Check if item is in map and cleanup
    }
}.start();
//Somewhere else in the main thread
Foo data = map.get("foo"); //Holds the lock for cleanup
if (data != null)
{
    //Stopping the lock can happen at any time to cancel timeout.
    data.getTimeoutLock().stop(); //Stop the lock timeout
    //Do my stuff
    //This is where the thread would check if I removed the data object.
    if (foo) //Random if that may or may not be true
    {
        map.remove("foo"); //Cleanup myself
    }
    data.getTimeoutLock().reset(); //Reset the lock timeout to what was set and continue timeout.
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). That might help identifying a possible solution.

Comment: @aha Hopefully the code example can more explain what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple map is not suitable for concurrent access/synchronization. You would need at least a [synchronized map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) or a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). But that's still not enough for a test-and-set scenario (e.g. "if key does not exist put key/value") because only the individual operations (like `contains()`) are thread-safe. Between `contains()` and `put()` another thread might access the map and invalidate the result from the `contains()` call. As a consequence you would need another lock. Example:

```
public class MapSample {

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void doSomething() {
        // Do not access/edit map except for simple read operations

        synchronized(lock) {
            // access/edit map…
        }

        // Do not access/edit map except for simple read operations
    }
}
```

But because you wait for something to happen I think a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) would be a more sensible solution:

```
public class LatchSample {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void doSomething() {
        // do something
        // signal completion after you did what you had to do
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void doSomethingAfterCompletion() {
        // will block until countDown() is called
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

If you have to wait repeatedly, use a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Recommended reading: [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net)

Comment: Using the cyclic barrier I can't find a way to stop and then restart the timeout for it's method await(int timeout, TimeUnit unit)

Comment: I think I have it fixed. I'll add another comment if I have any issues.
Thank you!

Comment: I simply iterrupted the thread(data.getTimeoutLock().stop(); in example) and then reset the CyclicBarrier(parties = 2) lock after I was done with everything.

Comment: This sounds wrong. You normally wait for the barrier to break and then it resets automatically.

Comment: I'll fix that. . . I was just following how my example was.

Comment: What would I do to stop the timeout, run some code, and then restart it(automatically)?

Comment: I'm guessing this is what I should do. Every time I thought of something to add/fix in a comment I was past the 5 minute edit limit. Sorry about that. :P